# When is the product of symmetric matrices symmetric?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

Suppose I have two symmetric matrices $A, B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. What qualifiers do I need to ensure that $B^{-1}AB$ is also symmetric? Is $B$ being diagonal enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $B^{-1}AB=B^{-1T}A^TB^T=(BAB^{-1})^T$, $B^{-1}AB-(B^{-1}AB)^T=(BAB^{-1}-B^{-1}AB)^T$, so the desired condition is equivalent to $BAB^{-1}=B^{-1}AB$ i.e. $[A,\,B^2]=O$, which occurs if $A,\,B^2$ are *simultaneously* diagonalizable. Clearly, however, not all diagonal $B$ satisfy $[A,\,B^2]=O$, even if $A$ is symmetric.

Comment: Thank you! What does the notation $[A,B^2] = 0$ refer to in your comment?

Comment: @spolk17 A [commutator of two matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Ring_theory).